# \marginpar with pushback from right

Tags: margins, marginpar

I like to put references to book sections pertaining to class notes in the right margin.  These are of the form XXXnn-nn for a 3-letter book title abbreviation followed by a range of section numbers.  Often the width of the marginal note exceeds the right margin I wish to use for the document.  I seek a way for the \marginpar to steal real estate from the current text line, making LaTeX think that the available line width is shorter than it really is, for only the current line.  It would be nice to be able to do this in a dynamically expanding way.  I would like the marginal note to be right-justified at the actual right margin end but to go as far left as needed.

Follow-up: I got a partial solution by setting \marginparsep to a negative number and then using \marginpar{\hfill foo}.  I have to make sure that lines on which \marginpar{} appears are not very long.

Comment: A picture demonstrating what you want would be helpful in understanding the question.

Comment: marginpar float down the margin they are not tied to a specific line so this would be tricky. You may be better using wrapfig to specify a 1-line cutout.

Comment: well it is easy to make marginpar work this way if you are prepared to use `\\ ` to force the short line by hand when needed.

Comment: This is against protocol but I have to say that it is such an honor to get a response from David Carlisle.  I don't think I want to force a short line using \\ as I would use extra vertical space in doing so.  Sorry I don't have a picture, but I'm imagining a line of marginal text 3 inches wide when the right margin is 1in, so that the note protrudes 2 inches into the text line and the text line is shortened by 2in.

Comment: Please note that (very nearly absolutely) ALL questions should include a minimal document demonstrating the issue (e.g. which reproduce the problem or error, or which set the situation up) starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. Help constructing minimal examples is provided [here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that?s=3|0.6280) and includes details of what to include and what to exclude.

Comment: I would strongly recommend against doing this, if I've understood the idea, which I may well not have. At least, if the notes are teaching notes, that's one thing. But if they are notes you plan to give to students, why make things so much more difficult to read than they need to be? A single line will not mark a clear distinction between the note and the text above and below it. I think this will be pretty confusing for anybody, but it will be make reading especially difficult for students with disabilities of various kinds or even certain non-disability eye conditions.

Comment: These are teaching notes and notes I give to students.  I'm not understanding your concern because the symbol I put in the right margin is clearly visible in all cases.  The main uses of these marginal symbols in my notes are (1) short mnemonics specifying a book and chapter where more information may be found and (2) a hyperlink to a sound file contain elaborations of the notes.